# Jest not finding my function and complains of a TypeError

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I created a Node.js application which exports a validate function. When I use the validator in a Jest test. Jest complains the validate is not a function. the function is clearly exported and when I click on it in VS Code, it goes right to the function.  Here is the validate function exported in a file called validator.js:

```
          // validator.js
             module.exports = {  
               validate: (req) => { 
               let policyType = req.body.policy_type;
               let length = req.body.term_length;
               
               if (!policyType) {
                return false;
               }
                if (!length) {
                 return false;
                }
                return  true;
               }
              };
```

I then pull in the function in the Jest test as follows:

```
        const validate = require("./validator.js");
        describe(“Validator Test", ()=> {
        test('Ensure expected return ', ()=>{
        const req = {};
        req.body.policy_type= '';
        req.body.term_length= '';
    
        //TypeError: validate is not a function
         expect(validate(req)).toEqual(expectedOut);
        
       })
```

Jest complains that validate is not a function. I simply don't know why it is complaining about not finding the function which can be found in other functions in the node application.  I searched online but could not find a use case like mine. As I am quite new to Jest, I would appreciate any help in resolving this. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I did not update the post. I solved it. The module.exports was fine.  The error was due to another export not being found that was used in the validator code. Once I fixed that, it was able to find the function

Comment: Thanks dariosicily for looking into this, really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module.exports works fine. The problem was related to another import which wasn't resolved in the validator.